# Weird mysql error, not accepting variants of word 'select' when inserting / updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have a couple of textarea fields, which get saved into the database as `text`. If the textarea input has a select, selected or selecting in it, the query fails. I've never encountered this before. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the update query code as an example:

```
$Query = "UPDATE project SET status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['status'])."', 
name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name'])."', 
summary = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['summary'])."', 
detail = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['detail'])."', 
category = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['category'])."', 
language = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['language'])."', 
updated_date = '".time()."', 
contact = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['contact'])."' 
WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";

$mysqlobject->sql_query($Query);

function sql_query($sql="")
{
    if(empty($sql)) { return false; }
    if(empty($this->CONN)) { return false; }
    $conn = $this->CONN;
    $results = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    if(!$results)
    {
        echo "<H2>Query went bad!</H2>\n";
        echo mysql_errno().":  ".mysql_error()."<P>";
       return false;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

The summary and detail fields take textarea data

Comment: run this what you get ? echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";

Comment: Why don't you use PDO to make your code both prettier and more secure?

Comment: @Haim - I'm getting an internal server error 500 even when error reporting is set to all.

Comment: @Borealid - I inherited the code, and I'm not given the time to prettify it.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code that causes this particular problem? `echo mysql_errno().":  ".mysql_error()."<P>";` - this already gets executed if the query fails. What is its output? Also let it show you the actual query, e.g. `echo mysql_errno().":  ".mysql_error().'<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($sql).'</pre>';

Comment: Btw, inherited code or not: At least your mysql class should expose an `escape($s)` method. Your code outside of the class using `mysql_real_escape_string()` without the link resource makes some bad assumptions and it may easily back-fire.

Answer (score 1):

You've omitted the code to interact with the DB. Nevertheless my guess is you're using a function which naively stops on the word SELECT in attempt to protect against SQL injection.